# Prolog rule for objects moving with people who have them

Tags: prolog, rule

If I have the following Prolog facts:

```
person(mary).
object(ball).
location(bedroom).
location(bathroom).
```

And this clause:

```
go(mary,bedroom).
get(mary,ball).
go(mary,bathroom).
```

I need a rule that shows that the ball travels with "mary." If queried, Prolog should reply that the ball is in the bathroom. I tried the following rules, but they didn't work:

```
has(X,Y) :- get(X,Y).
whereIs(P,R) :- has(P,Q),go(P,R).
```

What would be a better set of rules to express this relationship between between having objects and travelling to different rooms?

Comment: Why have has() if it is to be same as get() ? Also you may put '_' in place of Q since it does not seem to be needed.

Comment: What kind of query do you expect to enter and what kind of results? You say you need a rule that *shows that the ball travels with "mary"*. What kind of output exactly do you expect in order to show this? Or do you really just need a rule that tells you where the ball is? These aren't the same thing although one might imply the other.

Comment: Where do you want your facts to come into play? Your example code doesn't use them.

Comment: I need to know where an object is, so the user can ask "Where is the ball" and have Prolog essentially answer "Bathroom"

Comment: The facts indicate whether something is a person, place or thing. This is necessary so that the rules can be different according to what something is.

Comment: Your "clause", which is really a list of facts, will have issues in Prolog since it gives rise to a "discontiguous" warning. In some Prolog implementations, `go(mary, bathroom).` will be ignored since it occurs after `get(mary, ball).` which was after another fact using of `go/2`. A better way to express a sequence of information would be a list form, `[go(mary,bedroom), get(mary,ball), go(mary,bathroom)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works:

```
person(mary).
object(ball).
location(bedroom).
location(bathroom).

go(mary,bedroom).
get(mary,ball).
go(mary,bathroom).

whereIs(R) :- findall(R,(get(P,Q),go(P,R)),L), last(L,R),!.
```

On command:

```
?- whereIs(R).
R = [bathroom].
```

Basically, you want to find all locations of the person with the ball and then determine the last location.

I removed has() as it was essentially same as get().

Comment: Thank you so much!